# HP Pavilion x360 wireless problem

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.04, intel-wireless

I got a new HP Pavilion 13 x360 and I'm having issues with wireless. I've poked around here and ubuntu forums, but no existing solution for my problem seems to exist. I've installed Ubuntu MATE dual boot with Win10 and the wifi does not work (ethernet does tho and I'm connected to that). Here's the diagnostic commands I've used `lsmod`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  12 
bnep                   20480  2 
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         49152  1 uvcvideo
hid_sensor_rotation    16384  0 
hid_sensor_incl_3d     16384  0 
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     16384  0 
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  0 
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
hid_sensor_magn_3d     16384  0 
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  10 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  5 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
industrialio           57344  8 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_magn_3d
hid_multitouch         20480  0 
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  5 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
btusb                  40960  0 
videodev              159744  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
hid_sensor_hub         20480  7 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common
usbhid                 53248  0 
snd_hda_intel          36864  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
hp_wmi                 16384  0 
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
acer_wmi               20480  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm                   483328  0 
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
aesni_intel           172032  1 
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd                    90112  20 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
iwlwifi               196608  0 
joydev                 20480  0 
i915_bpo             1146880  3 
serio_raw              16384  0 
cfg80211              540672  1 iwlwifi
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
drm_kms_helper        131072  1 i915_bpo
shpchp                 40960  0 
drm                   348160  4 i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper
i2c_hid                20480  0 
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915_bpo
hid                   110592  4 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,usbhid
wmi                    20480  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
int3403_thermal        16384  0 
soc_button_array       16384  0 
video                  20480  2 i915_bpo,acer_wmi
int3402_thermal        16384  0 
hp_accel               28672  0 
int3400_thermal        16384  0 
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
hp_wireless            16384  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
acpi_pad               20480  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2 
psmouse               118784  0 
r8169                  81920  0 
ahci                   36864  3 
mii                    16384  1 r8169
libahci                32768  1 ahci
```

and `rfkill list all`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and `sudo lshw -C network`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for kimberlee: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a1500000-a1501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: dc:4a:3e:a6:28:75
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.248.225.93 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:128 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1404000-a1404fff memory:a1400000-a1403fff
kimberlee@Red-October:~$
```

I also tried `sudo rfkill unblock 0` and `sudo rfkill unblock wifi` with no output

the odd thing is that all other posts have `*-network DISABLED` from `lshw`
 where as I get `*-network UNCLAIMED`

thanks in advance

EDIT:
commands `uname -r`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ uname -r
3.19.0-32-generic
```

and `lspci -nn | grep 0280`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
kimberlee@Red-October:~$
```

and `lspci -nnk | grep 0280`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
```

and `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 3165`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 3165
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004010bc*sc*i*
```

and `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
```

Follow up to answer from chili555
here's `dmesg | grep iwl`
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    1.867282] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    1.881662] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-12.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.881677] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-11.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.881692] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.881694] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode' failed.
[    1.882090] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.882093] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode' failed.
[    1.882095] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

Almost there :-)
here's `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    1.997990] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.035497] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.17.12.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.120757] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[    2.121446] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.122164] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.194345] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   14.011836] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.012283] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  103.080577] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  103.081127] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

and `rfkill list all`

```
kimberlee@Red-October:~$ rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
kimberlee@Red-October:~$
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `uname -r` and also: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: My apologies, I really needed: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280` and I also need: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 3165` Sorry for my mis-step.

Comment: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Please add the subsystem information to the edit above. We're getting close, I promise!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device (and its subsystem) are covered by the driver `iwlwifi`. Let's load it and see if your wireless comes to life:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

If that brings up your wireless, let's get the system to load it automatically on boot:

```
sudo -i
echo iwlwifi  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

If it doesn't help, post any errors seen at the terminal and check the log:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

It appears that you lack the needed firmware. Please download this file to your desktop: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.17.12.0.tgz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.'

Now, back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.17.12.0
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3165-12.ucode
```

Reboot and let us hear the result. If the wireless is not working, again post:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

It appears that both `acer-wmi` and `hp-wmi` are loaded. Let's blacklist `acer-wmi`. First, if not already done, unload it:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r acer-wmi
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Comment: Hi `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` did not change anything, so I did not add it to etc/modules. I will append `dmesg | grep iwl` to my question

Comment: almost there! I have wifi indicator in status bar, but it's disabled. I tried `sudo rfkill unblock wifi` and that didn't change anything. will add `dmesg` and `rfkill list all` to my question

Comment: I assume the wireless button or switch has been moved but the `soft blocked:yes` doesn't change. Does it help to unload the module? `sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi`? If so, we'll blacklist it. Your newest `dmesg` looks great!

Comment: unloading acer-wmi seems to enable wifi but it won't search for networks.

Comment: Please check the Network Manager icon to be certain that 'Enable Wifi' is set. Also, what is the result of: `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`? We needn't see the entire output; just tell me if it sees networks including yours. I will edit my answer to cover blacklisting `acer-wmi`.

Comment: It fixed it! its connected to Wifi now :-) thank you so much

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour  The searchers will appreciate it. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

So, a few months later, the accepted answer works kinda-ok, but wifi connections sometimes go in and out and are often slow as compared to the same connection on the same computer in the same spot but using a Windows install, so I did a bit more digging with some of my own linux experience and found a chart from intel with some driver downloads that work better for my computer.

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html

so choose the right download for your own wifi device, then download it, unzip it. then `sudo cp iwlwifi${version}.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi${version}.ucode` where `${version}` is the version of the driver you downloaded. for me it was `iwlwifi-3160-14.ucode`. this was on a HP Pavillion X360 13t with the Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 device.